# Clone Android phone to VM (Virtual Machine)

Tags: backup, android-12, virtualbox

I was thinking about copying my phone to a VM for exploring and learning.
Without rooting my device, can I somehow clone it?

By cloning I mean dd / copying disk files and not downloading the same apps or recreating a similar environment.

Once I have the `raw.img` file of the phone, can I boot it as a `qemu` guest VM?

I wonder if there are any hardware issues that would prevent me from booting this new android VM, i.e. in case the android phone is Samsung then perhaps the whole Knox feature will prevent booting?

Comment: Cloning a device without root will not work. Even with root certain elements like private keys in the AndroidKeystore can not be copied.

Comment: Once root access is achived , besides issues like AndroidKeystore, will tge guest vm be a close enough copy of the real phone in term of processes, files and the such?

Comment: Kind of curious about the compatibility with the ARM (almost all Android devices) -> x86 (most PC devices) processor.

Comment: @chegov Of course not. My comment was only about cloning user data. Because of other hardware drivers and service processes the emulator is totally different. Changing that would require a lot of changes to the emulator and the used emulator image (on source code level). Getting the emulator to pass the Google SafetyNet test will be challenging. And you are correct that Knox is a problem on it's own.